# "Could not find a constructor that would match given arguments" returned when injecting a dbContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework, xunit, dbcontext, ihostedservice

**Context**

.NET 5 console application using the IHostedService pattern and EntityFramework Core 5.

**Issue**

The dbContext looks like this:

```
    public class WeatherDbContext : DbContext, IWeatherDbContext
    {
        public WeatherDbContext(DbContextOptions<WeatherDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }

       public virtual DbSet<Observation> Observations { get; set; }
}
```

The hostbuilder is configured thus:

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
        {
            logging.ClearProviders();
        })
        .UseSerilog((hostContext, loggerConfiguration) =>
        {
            logConfiguration.WriteTo.File(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LogFile"]);
        })
        .ConfigureServices((services) =>
        {
            services.AddHttpClient()
                    .AddSingleton<CommandLineArguments>(new CommandLineArguments(args))
                    .AddSingleton<StringWriter>()
                    .AddDbContext<IWeatherDbContext, WeatherDbContext>(options =>
                    {
                        options.UseSqlServer(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["WeatherManagerDatabase"].ConnectionString);
                    })   
                    .AddTransient<IWeatherUndergroundAPIService(x => new WeatherUndergroundAPIService(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StationId"],
                                                                                                      ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WUApiKey"],
                                                                                                      x.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>()))
                   .AddHostedService<DataDownloader>();                                                                                        
        });
```

...and the host service is constructed thus:

```
private readonly int importDayLimit;
private readonly ILogger logger;
private readonly StringWriter outputWriter;
private readonly int throttleLimit = 100;
private readonly IWeatherDbContext weatherDbContext;
private readonly IWeatherUndergroundAPIService wuApiService;
private DateTime FetchUpToDate;
private DateTime MostRecentlyRecordedObservationDate;

public DataDownloader(IWeatherUndergroundAPIService wuApiService,
                      ILogger logger,
                      IWeatherDbContext weatherDbContext,
                      StringWriter outputWriter,
                      CommandLineArguments commandLineArguments)
{
    this.wuApiService = wuApiService;
    this.weatherDbContext = weatherDbContext;
    this.logger = logger;
    this.outputWriter = outputWriter;
    this.importDayLimit = this.ProcessCommandLineArguments(commandLineArguments.Args);
}
```

I then have an XUnit test like this:

```
public class CommandLineArgumentValidation
{
    [Fact]
    public async Task CommandLineArgumentNotAnIntegerAsync()
    {
        // Arrange

        Mock<IWeatherUndergroundAPIService> mockWeatherUndergroundAPIService = new();

        DbContextOptions<WeatherDbContext> dbContextOptions = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<WeatherDbContext>()
            .UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: "testDb")
            .EnableDetailedErrors()
            .Options;

        IWeatherDbContext weatherDbContext = new WeatherDbContext(dbContextOptions);

        Mock<ILogger> mockLogger = new();
        
        StringBuilder consoleOutput = new();
        StringWriter consoleWriter = new(consoleOutput);
        
        CommandLineArguments commandLineArguments = new(new string[] { "not a positive integer" });

        DataDownloader dataDownloader = new(mockWeatherUndergroundAPIService.Object,
                                           mockLogger.Object,
                                           weatherDbContext,
                                           consoleWriter,
                                           commandLineArguments);
        
        CancellationToken cancellationToken = new(false);

        // Action

        await dataDownloader.StartAsync(cancellationToken);

        // Assertion

        Assert.Equal("Command line argument 'not a positive integer' is not a positive integer. Aborting download.", consoleOutput.ToString());
    }
}
```

The test throws an exception

> Castle.DynamicProxy.InvalidProxyConstructorArgumentsException : Can
> not instantiate proxy of class:
> WeatherManagerDataDownloader.WeatherDbContext.
> Could not find a constructor that would match given arguments:

Note that I've simplified the code for clarity. I *am* mocking other services that get injected to DataDownloader but I'm not mocking the dBContext. *EDIT: I've now added in the full code as it was noted that mocking appears to be occuring even though my simplified code didn't suggest that.*

**Question**

Why is this test exception occuring? As I see it mocking should have nothing to do with the dBContext passed in.

Comment: Try casting : WeatherDbContext((WeatherDbContext)dbContextOptions)

Comment: @jdweng Where exactly? In the test or in the DataDownLoader?

Comment: I would add break point and check the types before the calls.  You may be getting a null response that is giving issue.

Comment: The error suggests you are mocking WeatherDbContext, but your example code doesn't show that.

Comment: @Neil indeed it does but I can't understand why. I've updated the code above to show the full test setup. As you can see mocking is occuring but not for the dbContext.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* this may be the answer and certainly it's allowing me to move forward.

When running the test with debugger I realise that everything is being injected successfully and the tested code is proceeding successfully. However I'm testing an invalid command line parameter situation and in DataDownloader  I've coded

```
Environment.Exit(1)
```

to stop the app after outputing appropriate messages. Clearly that's not something you should do in an IHostedService and removing it makes the mocking error go away. Why it should cause a mocking error for something that hasn't been mocked remains baffling however.

Answer (score 0):

in your `WeatherDbContext` class, add another constructor or edit the last one without a parameter.

```
 public class WeatherDbContext : DbContext, IWeatherDbContext
 {
        public WeatherDbContext(DbContextOptions<WeatherDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        public WeatherDbContext()
        {
        }

       public virtual DbSet<Observation> Observations { get; set; }
 }
```